# Image scaling in internet explorer makes image get pressed by width

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

I'm working on creating a fallback image inside of my class that creates responsive images, but I am stuck with trying to fix a problem for IE. Since I cannot use things like `<source>`, `object-fit` and `srcset` I am up against a challenge. The image is placed underneath the content so it will size to the height of the div content. The image should cover the whole background of the div that contains the content, but the problem is that the width presses the image to this compact size that looks awful: [image: This is the image from IE wich looks bad.]

I will provide you with a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lxwesvf/7/ .
I made a copy of one of the wrappers it does exactly what it does inside of the IE. So I hope someone knows something about making the image not look all pressed by the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
height: 100%;
```

to this:

```
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
margin: auto;
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/sidhanshu28/pen/ERNwxz

Comment: thank you, but I now encouter that if I make the browser smaller the width becomes an issue.

Comment: change width to min-width:100% :)

Comment: now just one thing left and that's keeping the image centered :P

Comment: add margin:auto